# JPA EntityManager Nullpointer exception (which shouldn't be!?)

Tags: jpa, entitymanager

My ejb code:

```
@Stateless
public class EmployeeBean {

      @PersistenceContext(unitName="Eclipselink_JPA")
      private EntityManager entitymanager;


      public void createEmployee(){
          Employee employee = new Employee( ); 
          employee.setEid( 1201 );
          employee.setEname( "Gopal" );
          employee.setSalary( 40000 );
          employee.setDeg( "Technical Manager" );

          entitymanager.persist( employee );
          entitymanager.getTransaction( ).commit( );

          entitymanager.close( );

      }
}
```

Basically, nullpointer exception happens at the line where entitymanager.persist is called, which should not happen right?

My persistence.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence 
   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">

   <persistence-unit name="Eclipselink_JPA" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">

      <class>com.jpa.beans.Employee</class>

      <properties>
         <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:file:E:\HQLDB_AJ"/>
         <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="sa"/>
         <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="password"/>
         <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver"/>
         <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINE"/>
         <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables"/>
      </properties>

   </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I have eclipselink.jar and other eclipselink jpa jars in my class path.

Here is my entity beans:

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Employee {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)  

   private int eid;
   private String ename;
   private double salary;
   private String deg;

   public Employee(int eid, String ename, double salary, String deg) {
      super( );
      this.eid = eid;
      this.ename = ename;
      this.salary = salary;
      this.deg = deg;
   }

   public Employee( ) {
      super();
   }

   public int getEid( ) {
      return eid;
   }

   public void setEid(int eid) {
      this.eid = eid;
   }

   public String getEname( ) {
      return ename;
   }

   public void setEname(String ename) {
      this.ename = ename;
   }

   public double getSalary( ) {
      return salary;
   }

   public void setSalary(double salary) {
      this.salary = salary;
   }

   public String getDeg( ) {
      return deg;
   }

   public void setDeg(String deg) {
      this.deg = deg;
   }

   @Override
   public String toString() {
      return "Employee [eid=" + eid + ", ename=" + ename + ", salary=" + salary + ", deg=" + deg + "]";
   }
}
```

Whats seems to be the problem? can anyone help? ive been figuring this out of a day now.

Problem solved: i shouldn't be using resource local because i was running it in an app server. thanks for the help anyway. well appreciated

Answer (score 4):

When you set `transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL"` in `persistence.xml` config file, it means that YOU (=your application's code) will take care of creating `EntityManager` and also will handle transactions yourself. In such case what you can demand to be injected by your underlying container is `EntityManagerFactory` and you can do it by using `@PersistenceUnit` annotation. On such object you simply call `createEntityManager()` that gives you `EntityManager`.

If you want to use `EntityManager` supplied by the container you must specify `transaction-type="JTA"`. Then you annotate `EntityManager` exactly as in your code, and do not care of creating, committing or rolling back a transaction. It will be done by the container that will use `JTA` transaction and decide when to create, commit or rollback it.

Those two ways are commonly known as respectively **Application Managed EntityManager** and **Container Managed EntityManager**

You can find more details on how to work with each of two ways of handling transactions [here](http://tomee.apache.org/jpa-concepts.html) or [here](http://www.byteslounge.com/tutorials/container-vs-application-managed-entitymanager)

Comment: Excellent explanation

Answer (score 0):

You dont have `<provider>` in your persistence.xml.. Try adding it.

Ex:

`<provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>`
or `<provider>org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider>` or
`<provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>`
depending on your container.

HTH

Comment: thanks ill try. is the "org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider" built-in in eclipse? no need to add an additional jar in my class path?

Comment: no.. it is implemented by EclipseLink.. you might need to add the jar or maven dependency ```<dependency>
 <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
 <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa</artifactId>
 <version>2.6.0</version>
</dependency>
```